# What is the duration of 12 noon or midnight?

Tags: soft-question, time, terminology

We often say its 12 noon but What is the duration of midnight/noon. Is it in second/ millisecond/ microsecond or any other smaller quantity

Comment: Experimenter's practical answer that goes nowhere near the philosophical answer: roughly the smallest increment your clock measures, of course.

Comment: This is a question about language or philosophy or society, not physics.

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between a *time* and a *time interval*. Suppose we plot time on an axis something like this:

[image: Time axis]

A *time* is a position on the axis. A *time interval* is the distance along the axis between two times. For example I've drawn the time interval between 06:00 and 12:00, which has a length of 6 hours.

A time interval has a length, i.e. a *duration*, so for example the time interval I've drawn has a duration of 6 hours. However a time is just a point on the axis and does not have a duration.

So the answer to your question is that twelve noon does not have a duration because is is a time not a time interval. Of course in everyday life we may say *noon* and mean some vaguely defined time interval centred on or around 12:00, but that is is because everyday life frequently doesn't require the precision that physics demands of us :-)